# How can i securely store account data in an open source app?a

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb

I need to store user account data for my open source app such as email, hashed password, favourites etc.

The two options I have considered for this are: Storing info on a MongoDB Atlas database or storing in a JSON file.

Since the app is open source on GitHub, these two options create some problems. If MongoDB is used, then my API key will be exposed in the source code, which isn't that great. It will also make it difficult for people to test the project locally. If a local JSON file is used, users will be able to see all of a users sensitive info stored inside the repository, which definitely isn't good. What are my options here to be able to securely and easily control account creation and data storage? Cheers.

Comment: “*If MongoDB is used, then my API key will be exposed in the source code, which isn't that great.*” If you have an authentication/authorization model, why *in the world* are you even *considering* a direct connection to your database (which would necessitate this sort of design)? You should absolutely be abstracting all database calls away from clients such that database operations can be allowed/denied & logged based on your users’ access levels.

Comment: “*If a local JSON file is used, users will be able to see all of a users sensitive info stored inside the repository, which definitely isn't good.*” Then why commit the file to the repository instead of .gitignore-ing it? Why would it need to be committed? If your authentication/authorization model is implemented correctly on your server and client, neither of the issues you describe should be of concern regardless of whether or not your codebase is open-source.

Comment: Passwords should not be stored as **encrypted** value. Store **hash values** of the passwords.

Answer (score 0):

> Since the app is open source on GitHub, these two options create some problems. If MongoDB is used, then my API key will be exposed in the source code...

This is a good case to use environment variables on your local machine. In the code you can do something like

```
process.env.<APPLICATION_NAME>_API_KEY;
```

If the developers you're working with is trusted enough to handle *your* database credentials then you can share it behind closed doors.

> It will also make it difficult for people to test the project locally...

This is good practice for whatever future endeavors you might have with nodejs or other software development. Testing should never be made on production databases. If the database you're testing on isn't the production one, that's great, but there's still the issue with using sensitive user data for testing purposes. Banks *hopefully* aren't using real accounts to test transactions. What if there's an error and the account ends up drained with no log of how much was in it from the start?

I would recommend you setup a way to fill a database with dummy data for testing purposes. This could be a SQL script which you then can commit to your repo and update your instructions with how new developers and contributors can spin up their own database for testing purposes.